# Still get test ads with real ad unit Id

Tags: java, android, admob

I am testing and running my app on real device with real ad mob id from my ad mob account. The section of "Enable test devices" in google developer website say "When a device is configured as a test device, the Google Mobile Ads SDK automatically substitutes in sample ad unit ID, limiting that device to receiving test ads.". [Here is the link.](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#enable_test_devices) But I get only test ads. I have following code, layout file

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="my_admob_real_unitid"> </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Java code,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screentest);
        adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("8E99D553D3E0F7C7F7AAD92A33DCD0C3").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView.setAdListener(new MAdListener());
        if(adRequest.isTestDevice(this)){
            Log.i("Info","Test device");
        }else{
            Log.i("Info","Not a test device, beware..");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used

```
AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("8E99D553D3E0F7C7F7AAD92A33DCD0C3")
```

Either remove the test device or use another device.

Comment: Testing ads without addTestDevice is against the admob privacy policy. Isn't it? Will you please elaborate?

Comment: If you want non-test ads in your device, you must remove the test device. Clicking your own ads is against the rule. So to prevent the effect of accidental clicks, you should use test ads. If you use test device id of your device, tests ads will be shown only in your device, other devices will show original ads.

Comment: Do you mean, can I test my app with real ad unit Id but without addTestDevice()?

Comment: Yes you can, but you should **NOT** click your own ads.

Comment: But, according to google developer website "Testing with real ads (even if you never tap on them) is against AdMob policy and can cause your account to be suspended.". You can see "Always test with test ads" section here, https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

Comment: OK, so use test ads. what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to see real ads. Is it impossible?

Comment: It is possible. But do you want to break the rule? 

Comment: No, I don't want. Then, I can never see real ads during my app development process?

Comment: I am not a Google lawyer. It is completely upto you. 

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how real ads look, try to run it one any other device. If you want to see it on youurs, you can remove that addTestDevice Method. If you want both, do one thing. Check your build config while creating the AdRequest. If it is debug build, create AdRequest with AddTestDevice method and remove that method in release build.